# change DefaultConnection in MVC Accounts Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to Asp.Net MVC. My question is how to change DefaultConnection in the web.config file to use my entity framework connection string. my goal is one database in whole application.

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5, and entity framework database first. the other posts I found here, doesn't specify my problem correctly.

Just tell me if I have to bring more information. Thanks.

Comment: ?  not too sure what your asking here, are you trying to create other ways of accessing your database outside of entity framework, but using the entity framework connection string, if so just specify that connection strings?

Comment: No, because I have entity framework database first, in my web.config file, it builds another connection string named like "TestEntities", I want to have accounts table in my own database, not the one that is default of it... wanna more information?

Comment: so you have two databases ???

Comment: what happends when you create a new user for the first time?? it builds the database and it's tables on the behind, right?. I want this tables on my existing database. that's it.

Comment: in the conectionstring   change value of databasename to the name of your existing database

Comment: yeah, it can be done this way.. but now I have 2 connection strings in my web.config file... I need to be one... but it seems it can't be done directly, I'm about to found it out in the web... thanks for your time and solution @davethecoder...

Comment: delete one of the connection strings, not sure why you now have two, you must be doing some crazy stuff

Answer (score 9):

In you IdentityModels you should change the connectionString name:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Change the DefaultConnection to your testEntities.

Answer (score 1):

Find your AccountModels.cs/vb file and change

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("TestEntities")
    {
    }
...
}
```

I'm not sure if MVC 5 does the same initial file structure as MVC3- if so find in Filters folder InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs/vb file

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                ...
//change this
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("TestEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }...
        }
```

If those files aren't present. Do Ctrl+F and search ~Entire Project for DefaultConnection and replace it with your desired connection string from Webconfig